A few paths in path analysis violated linearity assumption, but other paths met the linearity assumption
I'm running a path analysis of serial mediation. Upon checking the linearity assumption, I found that a few paths do NOT have linear relationships, as indicated by rainbow tests and crPlots. However, other paths (i.e., most of the paths in the model) do have linear relationships.
In this case, I was wondering whether I can still run a regular path analysis that assumes a linear relationship? The paths that do not have linear relationships are between a predictor and two mediators (which are the first mediators in the serial mediation). I am interested to test the indirect effects that involve these variables. Can someone please advise?
I originally planned to run a path analysis with robust maximum likelihood, and huber white standard errors because my data is not normally distributed and have outliers.
Below are the crplots showing the deviation from linearity.
If running the planned path analysis is not appropriate, is any of the options below appropriate?
a. run a CFA and see the factor loading on the mediator, and see if the factors have a linear relationship with the predictor.
b. transform only the mediator (but not the predictor and outcome variables), and run the planned path analysis?


